# Find Quarter End Date between a set of Date - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I'm looking to see if it's possible to filter out a list of quarter ending date within a field containing date from a table.

Below is my code for grabbing a range of dates but how can I modify it to grab just the quarter ending dates? example for 2017 - I would want it to show `2017-03-31,2017-06-31,2017-09-31,2017-12-31`.

Thanks.

```
a.activity_date Between To_Date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and To_Date(Trunc(SysDate, 'Q') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
where activity_date >= date '2017-01-01' 
  and activity_date <  trunc(sysdate, 'q')
  and activity_date = trunc(activity_date, 'q') + interval '3' month - interval '1' day
```

The first two predicates are an adapted version of those of your original query (using date literals, and not using `to_date()` on what is a `date` already). The expression that is the right operand of the third predicate computes the end of the quarter for the current date: the logic is truncate the date the beginning of the quarter it belongs to, add 3 months, then substract one day. We can use that value for filtering.

We could also phrase this with bespoke Oracle date arithmetics:

```
where activity_date >= date '2017-01-01' 
  and activity_date <  trunc(sysdate, 'q')
  and activity_date = add_months(trunc(activity_date, 'q'), 3) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!